# Create assets and models on aws sitewise using ignition and iot sitewise bridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-core, ignition, aws-iot-sitewise

I am trying to create models and assets on iot sitewise using ignition software by inductive automations but not able to set it up. I have created sitewise bridge instance on aws, also have installed mqtt engine and mqtt transmission modules. Created servers and connected iot core (mqtt broker) with both MQTT ENGINE and mqtt transmission. Created UDT's instances and tags in ignition as well (getting data into these using external opc ua server via ignition's opc client), These UDT hierarchy and tags with values are visible in my ignition engine (in tag browser) as well. I thought once i am done with this setup, a model and rest of the stuff will get created on sitewise within a minute, as they've shown in their YT channel videos but it didn't work. ps - Both my mqtt engine and mqtt transmission modules are connected successfully.

Does anyone has any idea how i can tackle this ?

Also would like to apologies in advance for asking such broad question.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you had any luck with [Cirrus Link's forum](https://forum.cirrus-link.com/latest)? [for ignition specific MQTT questions], or the [official IA forum](https://forum.inductiveautomation.com/latest)?